# What HTTP code should REST return for a resource that is not ready after a 202 code?

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

Can't seem to find the answer to this question anywhere.  Have a service that when something is posted, it gets queued to be processed with a response code of 202.  The standard says to provide a pointer to a status monitor, which I have done, but what should I return if the client goes to the resource before the resource is ready?  I would think 404 except that the resource exists, just hasn't been processed yet.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://benramsey.com/archives/http-status-201-created-vs-202-accepted/) post:

> When the client checks the status URI later, if the item is still pending then the status URI might return a `200 OK` response with an entity body describing this. If the resource has been created, then perhaps the status URI would return a `201 Created` response with a `Location` header pointing to the location of the new resource. If the item was not created for some reason, then perhaps the status URI would return a `410 Gone` response. In this case, you should include an entity body explaining why the resource is gone, i.e. “We were unable to create this resource due to processing errors.” A `404 Not Found` response would also be acceptable, but the `410 Gone` response implies permanence; the requested resource is gone for good.

Seems relatively reasonable to me, except that `Location` header IMO is not particularly suited for this exact purpose.

Comment: Hey, thanks!  That makes a lot more sense. This is my first RESTful service to develop, so I'm still learning all of the nuances.

Comment: 200 OK response with human-readable body is very confusing for search engine crawlers, so I think it's not what you want.  201 Created means "this request created a new resource", so it's not suitable for polling.  410 is fine if you want to say to client "this resource is gone and never ask for it again".  404 sounds good since it says nothing about reason why resource is unavailable.  Most robots will retry request later, however it doesn't mean "come back later".